# Create Common Database Object

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have written SQL Server class and which contains all methods for insert, update, delete, execute stored procedure.

Now I have created a object of this class on Default page load and using class methods
to implement database operations.

Now if i am on second page and want to do database operation. I need to again create the database object.
Is there any way that can i only create it initially and use on other pages ?

Answer (score -1):

ASP .NET solves many of these issues with the help of User Controls.
by using user control you can do code re usability 
so you should go for user control

```
   bellow link help you to create user control
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET
```